# Can Cloud Foundry deploy chaincode to BlueMix

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, blockchain, hyperledger

Is it possible to deploy go blockchain code to a BlueMix blockchain service using cloud foundry from a private git repo?

The BMX chaincode REST api deployment descriptor warns:

> you will need to have the chaincode stored in a public git repository

The url deployment also relies on a public git repo:

> https://bluemix.net/deploy?repository=https://github.com/ibm-blockchain/marbles.git

I'm not having much luck finding an example cloud foundry manifest.yml configuration file to deploy straight from my private git clone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is currently possible, [see issue](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/issues/873).

If you do a local deployment you can test your chaincode without the need of having it in any repository. To do so follow [these instructions](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/API/SandboxSetup.md).

Edit: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433618/how-to-use-a-chaincode-thats-not-on-github) to see how to deploy chaincode in a local development setup without having it on github.

Comment: Thank you. The link explains why the repo needs to be public at the the moment.